# xen hypervisor wont boot from grub and "Can't find hypervisor information in sysfs!" error ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, virtualization, xen

I have used [This forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2008795), trying to run xen on my os:

steps i have done :

```
egrep '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
```

ouput = 4 and also i have run KVM virtualization with no problem.

then:

```
sudo apt-get install xen-hypervisor-4.4-amd64 xen-utils-4.4 xenwatch xen-tools xen-utils-common xenstore-utils virtinst virt-viewer virt-manager
```

then opened a console : Ctrl + Alt + F1 and :

```
sudo nano /etc/xen/xend-config.sxp
```

and appended to the last of the file these lines:

```
>     (xend-http-server yes)
>     (xend-unix-server yes)
```

skipped the network part coz i will manage them when every thing is right by bridge control utility .

then

```
ln -sf /usr/lib/xen-4.1 /usr/lib64/xen
```

did reboot

in my ubuntu when i loaded booted after restart, whenever i insert this terminal code:

```
xm dmesg
```

i get the error of

> ERROR:  Can't find hypervisor information in sysfs!

in that forum and alot searches of google it says to configure the /etc/grub.d .

i did these steps for:
attempt 1:

```
sudo mv /etc/grub.d/10_linux /etc/grub.d/50_linux
update-grub2
```

attempt 2:

```
dpkg-divert --divert /etc/grub.d/08_linux_xen --rename /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen
update-grub
```

Attempt 3:

```
mv /etc/grub.d/10_linux /etc/grub.d/20_linux && mv /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen /etc/grub.d/10_linux_xen
```

but even with that it gives the same error.

when i try to boot from xen hypervisro which has appeared in boot grub loader, no matter what kind of xen hypervisor boot loader i select, system goes plank (or purple color of ubuntu default color) and never starts.

is there any particular solution?

P.S:

> Ubuntu 14.04, AMD Mobility Radeon HD 5430/5450/5470 display ,4GB ram ,i3-370M -
>   2.40GHz cpu

Comment: I'm having the same problem. No solutions? Did you ever get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Although the [community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen) states that as of Ubuntu 14.04, GRUB will automatically choose to boot Xen first if Xen is installed, it doesn't if you don't run Ubuntu (16.04) in English.

To be able to select the right kernel at boot open /etc/default/grub

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and comment out the following 2 lines by putting a **#** in front of it and set GRUB_TIMEOUT to let's say 5

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
```

next update Grub and reboot

```
sudo update-grub
sudo shutdown -r now
```

You should now be able to to select the right kernel in the grub menu and boot your system with Xen enabled. If you want to boot your system with this kernel by default write down the translation of "Ubuntu GNU/Linux, with Xen hypervisor". In my case (Dutch) that's "Ubuntu GNU/Linux, **met** Xen-hypervisor" and open /etc/default/grub.d/xen.cfg when booted.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub.d/xen.cfg
```

Replace *GRUB_DEFAULT="Ubuntu GNU/Linux, with Xen hypervisor"* with *GRUB_DEFAULT="**translation**"* at the bottom of that file and undo the changes you made in /etc/default/grub. Update Grub again and reboot with Xen enabled by default ...

Answer (score -1):

This may help,
Found it somewhere in internet

```
dpkg-divert --divert /etc/grub.d/08_linux_xen --rename /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen
```

Comment: Answers without any trace of explanation make it very difficult to see their merit.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Just yanking a line of code (that didn`t resolve the problem) from the question does not qualify as an answer. Perhaps you can come up with a useful answer to one of these: http://askubuntu.com/unanswered